# gdm3: hide last user

Tags: gnome3, gdm3

This is supposed to disable the user list:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.login-screen disable-user-list true
```

However, gdm3 still shows a list of the users who were *logged in before*. How can I disable this? Gdm3 should always start with the "username" input field.

**Workaround:** I got this [from here](https://askubuntu.com/a/575390). We have to add `SystemAccount=true` to the files in `/var/lib/AccountsService/users`. I added the appropriate code to `/etc/gdm3/PostSession/Default`, so it is run whenever a user logs out. Seems to work; no more user lists in GDM.

Answer (score 0):

GSettings options are per-user; you need to change this for the "gdm" user account (which is used to display the login screen) and not for your own.

This is supposed to disable the user list:

```
sudo -i -u gdm dbus-run-session gsettings set org.gnome.login-screen disable-user-list true
```

Comment: Thanks, but not luck so far. It appears the culprit are files in `/var/lib/AccountsService/users`. I found people using lightdm also complaining about this. Now I need to find an elegant way to automatically delete files in that directory.